# Django REST: Uploading and serializing multiple images

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models `Task` and `TaskImage` which is a collection of images belonging to `Task` object.

What I want is to be able to add multiple images to my `Task` object, but I can only do it using 2 models. Currently, when I add images, it doesn't let me upload them and save new objects.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TaskImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskImage
        fields = ('image',)


class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    images = TaskImageSerializer(source='image_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for image_data in images_data:
            TaskImage.objects.create(task=task, **image_data)
        return task
```

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TaskImage(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

However, when I do a post request:

[image]

I get the following traceback:

> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py"
>   in view
>     95.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in handle_exception
>     454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py"
>   in create
>     21.         self.perform_create(serializer)
>
> File "/Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/godo/api/views.py" in
>   perform_create
>     152.         serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
>
> File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in save
>     214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
>
> File "/Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/godo/api/serializers.py" in
>   create
>     67.         images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
>
> Exception Type: KeyError at /api/tasks/ Exception Value: 'images'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Description for the issue**

The origin of the exception was a `KeyError`, because of this statement

```
images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
```

This is because the validated data has no key `images`. This means the images input doesn't validate the image inputs from postman.

Django post request store `InMemmoryUpload` in  `request.FILES`, so we use it for fetching files. also, you want multiple image upload at once. So, you have to use different image_names while your image upload (in postman).

Change your `serializer` to like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    images = TaskImageSerializer(source='taskimage_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'user', 'images')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = self.context.get('view').request.FILES
        task = Task.objects.create(title=validated_data.get('title', 'no-title'),
                                   user_id=1)
        for image_data in images_data.values():
            TaskImage.objects.create(task=task, image=image_data)
        return task
```

I don't know about your view, but I'd like to use `ModelViewSet` preferrable view class

```
class Upload(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
```

Postman console:

[image]

DRF result:

```
{
        "id": 12,
        "title": "This Is Task Title",
        "user": "admin",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Screenshot_from_2017-12-20_07-18-43_tNIbUXV.png"
            },
            {
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/game-of-thrones-season-valar-morghulis-wallpaper-1366x768_3bkMk78.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/IMG_212433_lZ2Mijj.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This is the answer for your comment.

In django `reverse foreignKey` are capturing using `_set`. see this [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward). Here, `Task` and `TaskImage` are in `OneToMany` relationship, so if you have one `Task` instance, you could get all related `TaskImage` instance by this `reverse look-up` feature.

Here is the example:

```
task_instance = Task.objects.get(id=1)
task_img_set_all = task_instance.taskimage_set.all()
```

Here this `task_img_set_all` will be equal to `TaskImage.objects.filter(task_id=1)`

Comment: You can use this git-repo if you want https://bitbucket.org/jerinpetergeorge/django_1_11/src/97728beb7b7979464f98ce50d9c70e7525a948ff/?at=SO-48756249

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I notice that in `serializers` you use `source=taskimage_set`, I'm not sure why this is so? It would make sense to be `task_image_set` or more generally, `model-field_set`, is this just a convention for use for one-to-many relationships?

Comment: Please have a look at **UPDATE** section at bottom of the answer,

Comment: When you create the TaskImage (```TaskImage.objects.create(task=task, image=image_data)```), should this not be created with the serializer? As without doing so, I would assume you are bypassing the validation stage, and saving the object without validation?

Comment: Not really, because the images are validated against the `serializer.ImageField()` field

Comment: I found a solution to a scenario where you can upload multiple images with form-data and send nested json. You can examine my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179429/8569342) .

Answer (score 1):

You have `read_only` set to true in `TaskImageSerializer` nested field. So there will be no validated_data there.

Comment: I removed it, but the error and traceback still the same