# Uploading Multiple Files using Django rest framework without using Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to Post, from Postman, multiple files to my django app.  I'm not using Forms, and there isn't a UI aspect to my app.  Here is a my view class.

```
class FileUploader(APIView):
    '''
    Rest API for FileUploader
    '''
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        retval = Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        logger.info('New post with the following data: {}'.format(request.data))
```

With this it says, "TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'META', 'input_data', and 'upload_handlers'"
If I use FormView, my Post has three keys, two represent files, the last is a string.  During debugging my request has no field Data, and FILES is empty, and the POST doesn't have any information.  Any pointers would be appreciated.  I can upload more if that helps.

It's not a duplicate because he was able to upload multiple files and mine doesn't upload any files.  I'm struggling to figure out how to find the files within the request and since they aren't there how to set up the views (and not the serialize) to receive multiple files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty9Gs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django REST: Uploading and serializing multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756249/django-rest-uploading-and-serializing-multiple-images)

Comment: moreover, you are not returning any response from your view class

Comment: I'm not concerned about making the Model from the request, so serialization isn't part of the problem, the problem is the physical POST request.  Later in the View I return the response either 201 or a depending.  What I'm struggling with is having both files contained within the request.

Comment: added an answer, try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a view class as

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class FileUploader(APIView):
    '''
    Rest API for FileUploader
    '''

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        files_list = request.FILES
        data = request.data
        return Response(data={"files": "{} files uploaded".format(len(files_list)),
                              "data": "{} data included".format(len(data))})
```

and send it using ***`form-data`*** in POSTMAN
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When I made these changes, data was a field, but had __len__ 0 and FILES was also zero.  So response was "{"files": "0 files uploaded", "data": "0 data included"}

Comment: How did you add the files and data? screenshot please

Comment: Just added the screenshot

Comment: And the header is Key = Content-Type Value = multipart/form-data

Comment: remove the header and try again

Comment: Worked perfectly, why did the header break it?  My own curiousity

Comment: Technically I don't know the ***explanation***, but POSTMAN will handle the content types whenever we click on `form-data` or `raw` etc

Answer (score 0):

change the above code to like below and include header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` in the request.

```
class FileUploader(APIView):
    '''
    Rest API for FileUploader
    '''
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        return Response({"message": "success"})
```

Comment: When I made the change, it failed saying "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems as you.

But this problem cause by my mistake when import package.

I should import `MultiPartParser` from `rest_framework.parsers` instead of from `django.http.multipartparser`

## ✅Right import

```py
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser
```

## ❌Wrong import

```py
from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser
```