# Multiple file upload DRF

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework, upload

I have a requirement which I would like to allow multiple files to be uploaded within the same post request to create an object. I currently have a method of doing this, but after looking at some other examples it doesn't appear to be intended way to do it.

models.py

```
class Analyzer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=False, unique=True)

class Atomic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class Submission(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated_at']

    issued_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    analyzers = models.ManyToManyField(Analyzer, related_name='submissions')
    atomic = models.ForeignKey(Atomic, verbose_name='Atomic datatype', related_name='submission', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BinaryFile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Binary file'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Binary files'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='binary_files')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/binary/')
```

serializers.py

```
class BinaryFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.BinaryFile
        fields = '__all__'

class SubmissionCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Submission
        fields = ['id', 'completed', 'atomic', 'analyzers', 'binary_files']

    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    completed = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    atomic = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=models.Atomic.objects.all()
    analyzers = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=models.Analyzer.objects.all()

    binary_files = BinaryFileSerializer(required=True, many=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        # # I dont really like manually taking invalidated input!!
        data['binary_files'] = self.initial_data.getlist('binary_files')
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):

        submission = models.Submission.objects.create(
            atomic=validated_data['atomic']
        )
        submission.analyzers.set(validated_data['analyzers'])

        # # Serialize the files - this seems too late to be doing this!
        for file in validated_data['binary_files']:
            binary_file = BinaryFileSerializer(
                data={'file': file, 'submission': submission.id}
            )

            if binary_file.is_valid():
                binary_file.save()

        return submission
```

Main question: While the above works, the child serializer (BinaryFileSerializer) doesn't get called until I explicitly call it in create(), which is after the validation should have occurred. Why does this never get called?

I also don't like the fact I have to manually do a `self.initial_data.getlist('binary_files')` and manually add it to `data` - this should have already been added and validated, no?

My thought is that as I defined `binary_files = BinaryFileSerializer`, this serializer should be called to validate that particular fields input?

FYI, I'm using the following to test POST uploads:

```
curl -F "binary_files=@file2.txt" -F "binary_files=@file2.txt" -F "atomic=7" -F "analyzers=12" -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4"  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/submit/
```

TIA!

**Update:** The question is now, if a validate() funciton is added to the BinaryFileSerializer, why does it not get called?

Comment: This is an interesting problem! I am thinking about how it is being serialized because each instance of the serializer has room for 1 'binary_file'  and youre sending multiple fields labeled as 'binary_file.' I am wondering how the serializer is handling this, my fear is that it either saves the first or the last and the rest get thrown out. You could possibly fix this by having your view have 2 serializers, one to handle the files, the other for the remaining information. The serializer for the files could then loop for each occurrence of 'binary_file' and return an array of files?

Comment: In terms of what it keeps, nothing . I never get binary_files in the validated_data, if I send 1, 2, or more fields!

Comment: I'm very new to DRF (and pretty new to Django), but I didn't know I could use multiple serializers! Can you link me?

Answer (score 7):

**Possible duplicate** --- [**Django REST: Uploading and serializing multiple images**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756249/django-rest-uploading-and-serializing-multiple-images).

---

---

From the [DRF Writable Nested Serializer doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers),

> By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create **`create()`** and/or **`update()`** methods in order to **explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.**

From this, it's clear that the child serializer (`BinaryFileSerializer`) won't call its own `create()` method unless explicitly called.

The aim of your ***`HTTP POST`*** request is to create new **`Submission`** instance (and **`BinaryFile`** instance). The creation process undergoes in the **`create()`** method of the **`SubmissionCreateSerializer`** serializer, which is you'd overridden. So, it will act/execute as per your code.

---

### UPDATE-1

**Things to remember**
1. AFAIK, we can't send ***nested `multipart/form-data`***
2. Here I'm only trying to implementing the least case scenario
3. I'm tested this solution with [**POSTMAN**](https://www.getpostman.com/) rest api test tool.
4. This method may be complex (until we found a better one).
5. Assuming your view class is subclass of **`ModelViewSet`** class

**What I'm going to do?**
1. Since we can't send the files/data in a nested fashion, we have to send it flat mode.
**image-1**
[image: img-1]

2. Override the **`__init__()`** method of the **`SubmissionSerializer`** serializer and dynamically add as much **`FileField()`** attribute according to the **`request.FILES`** data.
We could somehow use [**`ListSerializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) or [**`ListField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) here. Unfortunately I couldn't find out a way :(

```
# init method of "SubmissionSerializer"
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    file_fields = kwargs.pop('file_fields', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if file_fields:
        field_update_dict = {field: serializers.FileField(required=False, write_only=True) for field in file_fields}
        self.fields.update(**field_update_dict)
```

**So, what id `file_fields` here?**
 Since the ***form-data*** is a **key-value** pair, every file data must be associated with a key. Here in **image-1**, you could see `file_1` and `file_2`.
3. Now we need to pass the `file_fields` values from the `view`. Since this operation is creating new instance, we need to override the **`create()`** method of the **API class**.

```
# complete view code
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets


class SubmissionAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Submission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubmissionSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # main thing starts
        file_fields = list(request.FILES.keys())  # list to be passed to the serializer
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, file_fields=file_fields)
        # main thing ends

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

4. Now, all values will be serialized properly. It's time to override the **`create()`** method of the **`SubmissionSerializer()`** to map the relations

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
    validated_data_copy = validated_data.copy()
    validated_files = []
    for key, value in validated_data_copy.items():
        if isinstance(value, InMemoryUploadedFile):
            validated_files.append(value)
            validated_data.pop(key)
    submission_instance = super().create(validated_data)
    for file in validated_files:
        BinaryFile.objects.create(submission=submission_instance, file=file)
    return submission_instance
```

5. That's it!!!

---

### Complete Code Snippet

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile


class SubmissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file_fields = kwargs.pop('file_fields', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if file_fields:
            field_update_dict = {field: serializers.FileField(required=False, write_only=True) for field in file_fields}
            self.fields.update(**field_update_dict)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data_copy = validated_data.copy()
        validated_files = []
        for key, value in validated_data_copy.items():
            if isinstance(value, InMemoryUploadedFile):
                validated_files.append(value)
                validated_data.pop(key)
        submission_instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for file in validated_files:
            BinaryFile.objects.create(submission=submission_instance, file=file)
        return submission_instance

    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = '__all__'


# views.py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets


class SubmissionAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Submission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubmissionSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # main thing starts
        file_fields = list(request.FILES.keys())  # list to be passed to the serializer
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, file_fields=file_fields)
        # main thing ends

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

---

### Screenhots and other stuffs

**1. POSTMAN console**
[image: POSTMAN console]
**2. Django Shell**

```
In [2]: Submission.objects.all()                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[2]: <QuerySet [<Submission: Submission object>]>

In [3]: sub_obj = Submission.objects.all()[0]                                                                                                                                                                      

In [4]: sub_obj                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[4]: <Submission: Submission object>

In [5]: sub_obj.__dict__                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[5]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7f529a7ea240>,
 'id': 5,
 'issued_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 27, 8, 45, 42, 193943, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'completed': False,
 'atomic_id': 1}

In [6]: sub_obj.binary_files.all()                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[6]: <QuerySet [<BinaryFile: uploads/binary/logo-800.png>, <BinaryFile: uploads/binary/Doc.pdf>, <BinaryFile: uploads/binary/invoice_2018_11_29_04_57_53.pdf>, <BinaryFile: uploads/binary/Screenshot_from_2019-02-13_16-22-53.png>]>

In [7]: for _ in sub_obj.binary_files.all(): 
   ...:     print(_) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
uploads/binary/logo-800.png
uploads/binary/Doc.pdf
uploads/binary/invoice_2018_11_29_04_57_53.pdf
uploads/binary/Screenshot_from_2019-02-13_16-22-53.png
```

**3. Django Admin Screenhot**
[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate as far as I can see. I get what you say, which is why I have created a create() function in SubmissionCreateSerializer() and created the BinaryFile object there. I guess my question becomes, with the models above, how do I apply validation to the child serializer?

Comment: @geekscrap did you try this?