# DRF - create related objects alongside with the main object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models.

```
class Order(..):
   ...

class OrderImage(..):
   order = ForeignKey('Order...)
```

And I have a form with `dropzone.js`.

This form returns data suitable for creating an `order` using just `ViewSet` but it obviously doesn't create `OrderImage` objects, even there are `image[0]`, `image[1]` etc. data in the POST request.

What's the best way to create `OrderImages` alongside with the `Order` in `DRF`?

1. modify dropzone output (didn't find the way)
2. Modify request.data inside `ViewSet` (how?)
3. Modify OrderSerializer to create OrderImage objects?

How would you do that?

**EDIT**

```
class SubOfferImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubOfferImage
        fields = ['file']


class SubOfferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = SubOfferImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    client_status_display = serializers.CharField(source='get_client_status_display', read_only=True)
    system_status_display = serializers.CharField(source='get_system_status_display', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SubOffer
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields] + ['client_approve_url',
                                                                 'system_decline_url',
                                                                 'client_status_display',
                                                                 'system_status_display','images']
```

Now the problem is that I have raw images in the data, not serialized SubOrderImage objects.

I'm trying to change the input overriding `perform_create` but it doesn't seem to be a best option. The better would be to do that inside serializer.

Comment: IMHO, Modifying corresponding serializer (`OrderSerializer` ) would be nice

Comment: @JPG I've added images = OrderImageSerializer(many=True...) into the serializer but I need to somehow modify the json.

Comment: Can you add the pieces of information regarding the attempt you have tried with DRF nested serializer?

Comment: @JPG Done, It's at the bottom of the question. I'm trying to modify ViewSet.perform_create but it doesn't make sense.. it should work for updating too and I would rather do that inside the serializer.

Comment: It seems you are trying to upload image/file...is that right?

Comment: Yes I do. The main problem is with json format I think. Files are in binary format.

Comment: The very first valuable point is, ***You can't send image/image data using `application/json` formate***

Comment: Anyway, Does this answer your question, [**Django REST: Uploading and serializing multiple images**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756249/django-rest-uploading-and-serializing-multiple-images/48762785#48762785)

Comment: DRF has  [`FormParser`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser) which _can_ allow sending images as well as model data.  For writing the structures in a nested fashion, I recommend looking at [`drf_writable_nested` package](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) .  Consider also [Django REST Framework Bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk).  Lastly, you can send binary data in json if you b64 encode it on the client and then b64 decode it in your DRF endpoint.